# A library that assists in handling paste events of table data

Tags: open-source, javascript

I am working on a web application that has a markdown editor, like Github or Stack Exchange.

I want to allow users to paste table data into the editor. The table data could be pasted from a variety of sources, eg: Google Sheets, MS Excel, Apple Numbers.

The paste event clipboard data will differ slightly between each of these sources.

Is there a library that will assist in converting these various data sources to a GFM markdown table?